# rails 3.0 No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi all 
I recently updated my rails 2.3.5 application to rails 3.0

in rails 2.3.5 everything was ok, but in 3.0  i get an ActionController::RoutingError

> **No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"hours"}**

the line error is pointing to my form helper

```
<%= form_for(:hour, :url =>{:action =>'create'}) do |f| %>
```

in my routs file i have the following statement:

> match 'hours' => 'hours#index'

Can anyone tell me how can i fix it?. I will appreciate your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `rake routes`. `match 'hours' => 'hours#index'` gives you `GET /hours`.

The `form_for` tries to access a route `POST /hours`, which maps to `hours#create`.

Instead of the match-rule, try this instead:

```
resources :hours
```

Answer (score 2):

As Ariejan above stated - you need to have a route from the create action if that is what your form is using.

If you don't have all of the RESTful resources you can also limit the actions by using the follow parameter:

```
resources :hours, :except => [:destroy, :show]
```

or

```
resources :hours, :only => [:index, create]
```

The Rails Guides have good documentation. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html